# Retrieve item from list by string

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider this list:

```
l1 = ['Bio:PRJNA57967', 'Assembly:GCF_000007805.1']
l2 = ['Bio:PRJNA224116', 'Sample:SAMN07158965', 'Assembly:GCF_002318635.1']
```

Without considering that 'Assembly' is always at the last position, I want to retrieve this value.

Instead of to select the last element **l[-1]**, I need some suggestion where I can find 'Assembly' if it comes in another position of the list.

My command include these lines:

```
for i in l:
    if i.contains('Assembly'):
        print i
```

To skip a loop, is it possible to define my variable using a loop to search the element that I want to use?
like this:

```
name = ( i for i in dbxrefs  and i.startswith('Assembly:'))
```

Comment: if 'Assembly' in i?

Comment: You have posted 2 lists. Is `l` the first, or the second, or both? Is it a nested list?

Comment: @Rakesh you mean `if 'Assebly' in i:` not `l`.

Comment: in this case, how to retrieve their position? Because doing this of course that I get the name but not the element containing 'Assembly'

Comment: If you want to retrieve all items that contain `Assembly`: `result = [for i in l if 'Assembly' in i]`

Comment: @F.Lira Be specific about what you want. You have us running around chasing your thoughts otherwise.

Comment: I guess what you should have is a dictionary with the part before the colon as key and a list of the seconds parts as values.

Comment: In this case, I think `i.startswith` is better

Comment: you can use `next` towards `startswith`: `next(i for i in l if i.startswith('Assembly'))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `in` for the contains-check:

```
if 'Assembly' in i:
    print i
```

But, judging from your sample data, you could be more specific:

```
if i.startswith('Assembly'):
    print i
```

And if you want to exclude other `Assembly...:xxx` strings:

```
if i.startswith('Assembly:'):
    print i
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to look if a specific string use "in"

Example:

```
l = ['Bio:PRJNA57967', 'Assembly:GCF_000007805.1']
for i in l:
    if 'Assembly' in i:
        print(i)
```

Output

```
Assembly:GCF_000007805.1
```